# Fileupload Makes application Stops

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova-2.7.0

Here the code which i have used in my corodova 2.9.0 based application in Andorid .When i try to upload the photo.The Application gets crashed.

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI)
{
 Ext.Viewport.mask({ xtype: 'loadmask' });               
 var milliseconds = js_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss();
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey="file";
 options.chunkedMode=false;         options.fileName=App.gvars.userid+milliseconds+imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 renamedfile=options.fileName;
 options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
 var params = new Object();
 options.params = params;
 var ft = new FileTransfer();
 var url = "http://wish.brammies.com/itemimage/upload.php/";
 ft.upload(imageURI, url, win, fail, options,true);
 }
 function win(r)
 {
  console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
  console.log("Response = " + r.response);
  console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
 }
 function fail(error)
  {
   console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
   console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
   console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
 }
```

**EDIT**
PHP code

```
<?php 
$folder = “/itemimage/”;
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))  {  
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
     echo "File uploaded";
} else {
     echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
};
} else {
 echo "File is not uploaded.";
};
//you get the following information for each file:
echo $_FILES['file']['name']."</br>"; //represents the name of file uploaded
echo $_FILES['file']['size']."</br>";   //represents the size of file uploaded
echo $_FILES['file']['type']."</br>"; //represents the mime type of file uploaded
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']."</br>";
echo "fdggdr";
?>
```

Android running version **4.1.4**

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: post your stacktrace..

Comment: @kalyanpvs here the stacktrace http://pastebin.com/UFyFHzZA

Comment: have you written your code native??

Comment: @kalyanpvs its phonegap based application.Works with Android

Comment: Can you please check this line from your log cat: Division by zero in /home/lamaire/public_html/ftp/itemimage/upload.php on line

Comment: @SubramanianR i have updated my php code in question.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set options.chunkedMode=true;

When chunked mode is false the HTTP code on Android tries to buffer the entire transfer in memory before sending. With larger transfers 15 mb in your case but for other phones it will be even less as they will have less memory this will cause an OutOfMemory Exception to be thrown. Since an OOME should never be caught the application will crash.

Comment: i did .But still its crashing